# Как вернуть 2 переменные в С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Для задачи нужно из функции вывести 2 переменные. Как это сделать?

```
double Kovalev::func3(double a, double b, double c){
    double d = Dis(a, b, c);
    double x1 = (-b+sqrt(d))/2.*a;
    double x2 = (-b-sqrt(d))/2.*a;
    return x1, x2;
}
```

Comment: Можно передать в функцию указатель на структуру, в которую следует попожить эти переменные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
std::pair<double, double> Kovalev::func3(double a, double b, double c){
double d = Dis(a, b, c);
double x1 = (-b+sqrt(d))/2.*a;
double x2 = (-b-sqrt(d))/2.*a;
return std::make_pair(x1,x2);
}
```

Comment: Или просто возвращать структуру (`struct d_res { diuble x1, x2; };`), содержащую эти переменные.